# What are the Dispatch/Execute() functions and how do they work?

Tags: magento2, controllers, action

I would like an explanation of the **dispatch and execute functions**, the differences between them, when they are/should be used and how.

***Please limit your answer to Magento 2***

Comment: Have you looked at the code and/or documentation, or do you expect an essay from someone?

Comment: It's a question website. Unless my question is duplicated or against the guidelines, don't complain about me asking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming here you're referring to the Action class `dispatch()` method and not about the `Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface` method (that dispatches an event to be used in the observer).

In general terms:

- the front controller `Magento\Framework\App\FrontController` **dispatches a request and gets a result object**.
- the app `Magento\Framework\App\Http` in the `launch()` method **copies HTML to the response object.**
- the bootstrap `Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap` **flushes that HTML from the response object to the browser.**

An action class usually extends `Magento\Framework\App\Action` here's a class diagram:

[image]

The `ActionInterface` has only two methods: `dispatch()` and `response()`

To get a good overview of the high level execution flow here's another diagram:

[image]

Here's a summary of the flow:

- The `FrontController::dispatch()` is called from the `app::launch()`
- It finds the correct router, which then finds the correct action class.
- The front controller class an action class that then calls `dispatch()`. `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` is where the `dispatch()` method is implement; it then calls the `execute()` method

To make more sense, I reckon you can check the `dispatch()` method from `Magento\Framework\App\FrontController` which performs action and generate the response:

```
public function dispatch(RequestInterface $request)
{
    \Magento\Framework\Profiler::start('routers_match');
    $routingCycleCounter = 0;
    $result = null;
    while (!$request->isDispatched() && $routingCycleCounter++ < 100) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface $router */
        foreach ($this->_routerList as $router) {
            try {
                $actionInstance = $router->match($request);
                if ($actionInstance) {
                    $request->setDispatched(true);
                    $this->response->setNoCacheHeaders();
                    if ($actionInstance instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction) {
                        $result = $actionInstance->dispatch($request);
                    } else {
                        $result = $actionInstance->execute();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException $e) {
                $request->initForward();
                $request->setActionName('noroute');
                $request->setDispatched(false);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    \Magento\Framework\Profiler::stop('routers_match');
    if ($routingCycleCounter > 100) {
        throw new \LogicException('Front controller reached 100 router match iterations');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Unlike in M1, where the router would implement everything, **in M2 the action instance implements `dispatch()` and it must also implement `execute()`**

The `execute()` method actually processes the URL. When someone enters a URL, it winds up in the action class (of a controller). It is where you implement your logic.

The `dispatch()` method is less likely to be implemented in custom modules. Most cases where you will have to do so are:

- Check whether a customer is logged in (see [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Address.php#L123))
- Check whether a payment method is enabled (see [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Controller/Paypal/AbstractAction.php#L53))

Source: Fundamentals of Magento 2

Comment: You said that both must be implemented but your link only implements dispatch?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Address.php#L123

Comment: @LM_Fielding When I said both must be implemented it's on the action instance level, not on the action class level. Check the diagrams, it's easier to understand with them

Comment: So it's implemented via inheritance in that case? Apologies.

Comment: @LM_Fielding that's correct